# How to get the linux thread id from RWThreadId?

Tags: pthreads, rogue-wave

In the RW [documentation](http://www.roguewave.com/Portals/0/products/legacy-hpp/docs/thrref/rwthreadid.html) it advises to use rwThreadHash to get the threadId for debugging but that still doesn't match the actual linux thread id on a thread. Any idea how to get it (not necessarily in a portable way)?

```
cout << rwThreadHash(threadId()) << endl;
1477159840
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [gettid()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/gettid.2.html)

From the [pthread_self() man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_self.3.html) notes:  The thread ID returned by `pthread_self()` is not the same thing as the kernel thread ID returned by a call to gettid(2).  What you are printing out looks like a pthread id.

Comment: I know I can you use the pthread calls to get the *current* tid, but the problem is that I am actually using a library that's returning a RWThreadId of a thread that it manages and I have no access to so that's why I am trying to convert from one type of thread id to the normal linux based one.

Comment: The pthread id and the kernel thread id are two different entities.  You seem to have access to the former but want to access the latter.  Presumably RogueWave gives you some way to specify the function/method that will run in the thread.  You need to put gettid() in that method to return the kernel id or at least display it in a log.  If you are saying that the thread is running some library code which you can't change then you might indeed be SOL.